# Calculate 12v Battery Runtime When Using Only 3.6v

Tags: batteries

What is the best way to calculate the runtime of a 12v battery if I am using 12 - 1 watt LEDs using 320mA @ 3.6v? Can someone post the formula?

Comment: How do you step down the voltage? So you plan on putting the LEDs in parallel?

Comment: Parallel and I plan on using a voltage regulator to step down from 12v to 3.6v.

Comment: Switching or linear regulator? If switching, what's the expected efficiency?

Comment: Actually I just realized I have a buck converter laying around so I would be using that.

Comment: You should _really_ put details like that (and more) in the question. Without it, this is impossible to answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we have:

- 12 LEDS with Vf=3.6V and Iftot=320mA when in parallel (If=24mA per LED).
- 12V battery with let's say 1000mAh (you haven't specified the capacity)
- The battery voltage will be regulated down to 3.6V with voltage regulator

Assuming you use a switching regulator with 100% efficiency we can calculate:

Ibat = Vf / Vbat * Iftot = 96mA

Thus the battery would last:

t = 1000mAh / 96mA = 10.41h

Since a switching regulator has more like a 80-90% efficiency, expect 10-20% less.

If you use a linear regulator like the LM-series, the difference between the input and regulated voltage is dissipated as waste heat. Then it would just be:

t = 1000mAh / 320mA = 3.12h

And your regulator would get pretty hot (P= 12V - 3,6V / 320mA = 2.7W).

Comment: With a linear regulator (and from a prior post, the OP has to have this all working in a few hours' time), the efficiency will be 30%. So the time will be a LOT less, if that's all he has to work with.

Comment: Battery would be a 80Ah starting battery.

Comment: @jonk: Supplemented info for linear regulator.

Comment: Yeah a regulator would be out. I have a buck converter that I can also use.

Comment: @Mr.SCW: Well, then everything should be clear? ;) (PS: a buck converter is also a regulator, the LINEAR is the thing you do not want)