# Calculating battery run time

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, time, capacity

How long will a 12 V, 35 Ah battery powering a 5 V, 1 A device last? Yes, there is a 12-5 V converter in this circuit.

Is the correct method for finding the solution to convert both sources to watts and calculate that way?

Comment: When calculating with Wh, figure in converter efficiency and depth of discharge (has influence on the useful life of a rechargeable battery).

Comment: Do you want the battery to be re-usable or will it be sent for recycling after one discharge?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate 12v Battery Runtime When Using Only 3.6v](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/269627/calculate-12v-battery-runtime-when-using-only-3-6v)

Comment: Close, but you can't convert both to watts. Convert one to W, the other to Wh. Dividing Wh by W will give you ... hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **roughly** estimate by converting the battery capacity to watt-hours and the load to watts.

Battery capacity: 12V x 35Ah = 420Wh
Load: 5V x 1A = 5W
Runtime: 420Wh ÷ 5W = 84 hours

Be aware this is just a rough estimate. In reality, the battery voltage is not constant, the capacity can be significantly reduced if the load is too high for the battery (your load is *not* too high for your battery), and the converter wastes some power which should be added onto the load power.

We use watts because the switching converter makes the input watts the same as the output watts. If you are using a linear regulator instead (you shouldn't), the calculation should be done with amps (35Ah ÷ 1A = 35 hours) because a linear regulator keeps the amps the same on the input and output side. Of course if the load voltage is the same as the battery voltage then you don't have a converter at all, and both formulas give you the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use a DC/DC converter and not a linear regulator, the "watt way" is a good way of calculating this. So:

The battery's capacity is 12 V × 35 Ah = 420 Wh.
The device consumes 5 V × 1 A = 5 W.

Everything being ideal and 100% efficient, that would give you 420 Wh / 5 W = 84 hours of battery life.

In real life, you need to factor in:

- the efficiency of the DC/DC converter at the current you pull;
- the voltage of the battery dropping while it is being discharged;
- the capacity of the battery at the current you pull from it, which may be different from the capacity quoted by the manufacturer (which is quoted at a defined discharge current which may be different from yours);
- the percentage of the battery capacity you intend to use before recharging (this influences cycle life, which may be a consideration).

Comment: If the 5 V regulator is a linear regulator, then the efficiency is 5 / 12 = 42 percent. If it is a DC-DC converter, then use the true efficiency if you know it, or estimate it at 80 percent as a good guess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for a **rough estimate** you can calculate the power consumption of your load. That power has to be delivered by your battery, so you can calculate the battery current from power and battery voltage.
Having the battery current you are then able to calculate the runtime  with the battery's capacity.

For a more accurate answer you need to take things like converter efficiency and the discharge characteristic of your battery into account.